# QTDesigner (5.4) Dock views are in separate windows in Mac. How to make them in one?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer, dock

Qt Designer (5.4) Dock views are in separate windows in Mac. How to make them in one window?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open the preferences dialog:

```
Settings > Preferences...
```

then click on the `Appearance` tab, and select:

```
User Interface Mode: Docked Window
```

Comment: Comment: preference dialog refers to the one of QT Designer, not macOS